# MongoError: Can't canonicalize query

Tags: mongoose

This is the exact error that I receive

MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: $set: { players: [ "1382306895402433" ] }

My mongoose query looks something like:

```
  FollowModel.findOne(
    {userId: req.user.userId},
    {$set: {players: req.body.players}},
    {upsert: true, 'new': true},
    function() {
      res.status(200).send();
     }
  );
```

req.body.players = [1382306895402433];

in my schema, players has been defined as an array.

Do why does mongoose throw an eror ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$set` as well as `upsert` are update operators, and cannot be used for find queries. I think you mean to use update.

```
FollowModel.update(
    {userId: req.user.userId},
    {$set: {players: req.body.players}},
    {upsert: true, 'new': true},
    function() {
      res.status(200).send();
     }
  );
```